# Help explaining an svg arc command

Tags: svg

I have recently gotten an SVG snippet from some website, shown below. Although this is doing somewhat similar to what I want (a half circle), I am having issues fixing it to accommodate my needs. Could someone explain what each part of the following snippet means?

```html
<svg width="256" height="256">
  <path d="M 128,128 L 128,0 A 128,128 1 0,1 256,128 Z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters in the `d` attribute of paths stand for certain commands. The numbers are coordinates or other parameters of each command.

- `M` stands for "move", specifically move to the exact coordinates that follow (as opposed to `m` which stands for move relative to the current position). The `128, 128` is the `x, y` to move to.
- `L` stands for (straight) "line" to the next coordinate(s).
- `A` stands for "arc" (specifically an oval-shaped arc) following the following format: `rX,rY rotation, arc, sweep, eX,eY`.
- `Z` then closes the path by drawing a straight line directly back to the last place the "pen" was set down (probably the last `M` or `m` command).

For more information on how all of the parts of the `d` attribute of paths works, see [this very helpful CSS-Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Appreciate it and sorry for the delayed accept :)