# Understanding SVG Path element

Tags: svg, path

I am reading and learning about SVG paths here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

I don't get the point with the path in the following code:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path d="M10 10"/>

  <!-- Points -->
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="2" fill="red"/>

</svg>
```

Even when i remove the path element, I can't see any changes in the circle position or whatsoever. Can some one explain what is path doing in this example?

Comment: Its preparing to draw, its a stray point, which may or may not be visible depends on implementation. Incidentally the thing inside d= is actually PDF notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not doing anything. As [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/120137/23061) says, the `M` just means "move to 10, 10". There are no other commands, so it's not doing anything.

Looking at the page, it seems they're setting up the demo for future examples.